# Graph according to column with ggplot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame like the following:

```
                     Date and Timestamp    Name FP  
NA                                 <NA>    <NA>           NA  
39 Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM 1500485400000 Unknown        0.004  
40 Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM 1500486300000 Unknown        0.006  
41 Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM 1500487200000 Unknown        0.003  
42 Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM 1500488100000 Unknown        0.008  
43 Jul 19,2017 2:55:01 PM 1500487200000 Unknown        0.002  
44 Jul 19,2017 2:55:01 PM 1500488100000 Unknown        0.008  
45 Jul 19,2017 2:55:01 PM 1500489000000 Unknown        0.006  
46 Jul 19,2017 2:55:01 PM 1500489900000 Unknown        0.003  
47 Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM 1500492600000 Unknown        0.008  
48 Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM 1500493500000 Unknown        0.014  
49 Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM 1500494400000 Unknown        0.017  
50 Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM 1500495300000 Unknown        0.014  
51 Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM 1500494400000 Unknown        0.007  
52 Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM 1500495300000 Unknown        0.013  
53 Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM 1500496200000 Unknown        0.018  
54 Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM 1500497100000 Unknown        0.007  
55 Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM 1500498000000 Unknown        0.012  
56 Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM 1500499800000 Unknown        0.005  
57 Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM 1500500700000 Unknown        0.012  
58 Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM 1500501600000 Unknown        0.011  
59 Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM 1500502500000 Unknown        0.007
```

I would like to do a ggplot that graphs according to the Date/hour/FPS column. Since it is already organized I want to graph from row 1 all the way to 4 in the order of the rows. The x-axis would be FP and the y-axis would be the Date/hour/FPS, with labels slanted 90 degrees.

Right now I have this:

```
ggplot(databyname, aes(x = databyname$`Date and Timestamp`,
    y = databyname$FP)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_line()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

The problem is that it's trying to organize Date and Timestamp  instead of just graphing it by row. FP doesn't show. Thanks in advance.
Graph: https://ibb.co/iqJd4k

Comment: Try adding `scale_x_datetime()`?

Comment: And check in `str(databyname)` that `Date and Timestamp` is stored as a date type, and not text. If it's not, try `databyname$"Date and Timestamp" <- as.date(databyname$"Date and Timestamp")`

Comment: i found a way to do it.i added a row that went for 1to 15 to the data from by doing
 c=nrow(databyname)
databyname$rowid<- 1:c
and the using the reorder command 
ggplot(databyname, aes(x =reorder(databyname$`Date and Timestamp`,databyname$rowid), y = databyname$Total_Frames)) +
  geom_line()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
the problem now is that i can't make it graph the FP

Comment: graph ->https://ibb.co/dWGWPk

Comment: can u help making it plot the dots and lines now

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Please provide a sample of your data using `dput()`, instead of a plain-text table.

Comment: Now i was able to plot points but not lines using this
ggplot(databyname, aes(x =reorder(databyname$`Date and Timestamp`,databyname$rowid), y = databyname$Total_Frames)) +
  geom_point()+ geom_line()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ggtitle(name2)+xlab('Date and Timestamp')+ylab('Total Frames')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add a reorder to the ggplot therefore u need to add a column in the datagram from 1-15 to make it reorder by the row. like this:

```
c=nrow(databyname)  
databyname$rowid<- 1:c
```

then u plot it using this

```
ggplot(databyname, aes(x =reorder(databyname$`Date and Timestamp`,databyname$rowid), y = databyname$Total_Frames,group=1)) +
  geom_point()+ geom_line()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ggtitle(name2)+
  xlab('Date and Timestamp')+ylab('Total Frames')+geom_line()
```